# how to share information from SharePoint to JavaScript? SAPUI5 proyect

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sapui5

I'm trying to integrate SharePoint to JavaScript in a SAPUI5 project.

I implemented the project in VS Code but it does not work because AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) compatibility with the framework SPPull, which provides a simple solution to my problem

I download the folder from the library (named SPPull), I saved into folder libs and implemented into manifest.json

```
"resources": {
            "js":[
                {
                    "uri":"libs/sppull/dist/index.js"
                }
            ]
```

when I call it from the controller using this:

```
var sppull = require("sppull")
```

it throws require is not defined.

any thoughts? thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

I assume the JSON fragment you posted is your manifest.json file. You need to refer to the library using your app namespace in sap.ui.define at the beginning of your controller. So, if the controller you're trying to import sppull is App.controller.js, it will look like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "mySapUI5App/js"
],
    /**
     * @param {typeof sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller} Controller
     * @param {typeof mySapUi5App.js} SPPull index.js
     */
    function (Controller, js) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("com.urlshortener.grilo.urlshortener.controller.App", {
            onInit: function () {
               ...
            },
            onBeforeRendering: function() {
               ...
            },
            //other controller methods here

        });
```

where "mySapUi5App" is your app's namespace, defined in index.html under script tag "data-sap-ui-resourceroots":

```
   <script
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "mySapUI5App": "./"
        }'
    ></script>
```

I would rename "js" to "Index" so it matches the pattern of module requirement in sap.ui.define. You can also refer to the full qualified name of the file as "mySapUI5App/dist/libs/sppull/dist/index" in sap.ui.require. This should resolve your problem.